# Why Include path works only without "/" in start?

Tags: php, include

I want `index.php` to include a `footer.html` file located in the `include` folder which is on the same folder where my `index.php` is located.

I noticed that it wouldn't work if I use:

`<?php include '/include/footer.html'; >`

I will get :

> Warning: include(/include/footer.html): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in

It will only work if I use:

`<?php include 'include/footer.html'; >`

This is confusing because at the same time, I do use the first form to include scripts and images:

`<script src="/js/script.js"></script>`

`<img src="/images/logo.jpg">`

Btw, is it better to concentrate all included files in a designated folder?

Comment: server side / is root of server; client side its web-server root.

Comment: you can use`./` ie `'./path/to/file.html'` which is relative to your document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion is that PHP's `include()` looks for files based on their physical file path on the server itself. It has nothing to do with your URLs.

You can do:

```
<?php include './include/footer.html'; >
```

Or:

```
<?php include 'include/footer.html'; >
```

Or:

```
<?php include __DIR__ . '/include/footer.html'; >
```

If you `<?php echo __DIR__ . '/include/footer.html'; ?>`, you'll see the full path on disk to `footer.html`. On Linux/UNIX systems, `/` is the root directory of the system, so when you use `/include/footer.html`, it's looking for a directory called `include` in the system's root directory, and a `footer.html` inside it.